# inserting data in the database using object oriented programming

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a code for entering the students name and roll_no in the databse through php using codeignitor but some error is been displayed like:
the controllers code  is

```
class Stud_controller extends CI_Controller{
function __contruct(){
    parent::__contruct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
     $this->load->model('Stud_Model');
     $this->load->database();
```

the model code is as follows:

```
class Stud_Model extends CI_Model{

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();

        }
```

the error is as follows:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\wamp64\www\codeignitor\CodeIgniter-3.1.2\application\controllers\Stud_Controller.php on line 13
>
> PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Stud_controller::$db
>
> Filename: controllers/Stud_Controller.php
>
> Line Number: 13
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp64\www\codeignitor\CodeIgniter-3.1.2\application\controllers\Stud_Controller.php
>   Line: 13
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\wamp64\www\codeignitor\CodeIgniter-3.1.2\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

so if anyone can please help me to solve the error.

Comment: Where is `Stud_Controller.php Line: 13 Function: _error_handler`? you are calling `$db` which is `Undefined`.

Comment: the  13th line code is as follows :                                 public function index(){
   
   $query=$this->db->get("stud");
   $data['records']=$query->result();
   $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->view('stud_view',$data);
  }

Comment: So then `$this->db` but there is not much more I can say on the matter without a bit more code.

Comment: sir which part of code you like to see i would provide you with that part of code..

Comment: don't forget to setting your database in `application/config/database.php`

Comment: I am not familiar with codeignitor just know where you needed to look based on the error.

Answer (score 0):

COntroller:

```
 class Stud_controller extends CI_Controller
        {
        function __contruct()
        {
             parent::__contruct();
             $this->load->helper('url');
             $this->load->model('Stud_Model');
        }
        public index()
        {
        $data['records'] = $this->Stud_Model->get_records();
        $this->load->view('stud_view',$data);
        }
```

Model :

```
class Stud_Model extends CI_Model{

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

        }

        public function get_records()
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('stud');//stud is your table name
            return $query->result_array(); //returns result in array format
        }
```

In your view fetch records using foreach loop as below:

```
foreach ($records as  $record) {
    //your operation
    echo $record['column_name']; //column name is your db table col name
}
```

Comment: no sorry sir its not working still same error is been displayed.

Comment: don't forget to setting your database from `application/config/database.php`

Comment: the config for database is as follows:$db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'root',
 'password' => '',
 'database' => 'stud',

Comment: `stud` is your table name..set there your database name

Comment: i also tried that stuff but not working actually i have created table and database name same

Comment: active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'root',
 'password' => '',
 'database' => 'stud',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => TRUE,
 'db_debug' => TRUE,
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);

Comment: 'pconnect' => FALSE,